# How to add /D[0/Fit] command to pdf using PDActionRemoteGoTo class in pdfbox?

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, pdfbox

I have implemented functionality to add links to file in a pdf using pdfbox. Below is the code that I am using:

```
 PDAnnotationLink txtLink = new PDAnnotationLink();
 PDActionRemoteGoTo remoteGoto = new PDActionRemoteGoTo();
 PDComplexFileSpecification fileDesc = new PDComplexFileSpecification();
 file.setExecutable(true);
 fileDesc.setFile(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath));
 fileDesc.setFileUnicode(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath));
 fileDesc.setFileDescription("");
 remoteGoto.setOpenInNewWindow(true);
 remoteGoto.setFile(fileDesc);
 txtLink.setAction(remoteGoto);
 txtLink.setRectangle(rect);
 page.getAnnotations().add(txtLink);
```

The links generated are working in windows based pdf editors, but do not work in pdfviewer for ios. The commands entered in pdf using the above code is:

```
12 0 obj
<<
/Type /Annot
/Subtype /Link
/A 17 0 R
/Rect [1578.599 316.56006 1600.6244 326.62427]
>>
endobj
17 0 obj
<<
/S /GoToR
/NewWindow true
/F 20 0 R
>>
endobj
20 0 obj
<<
/Type /Filespec
/F (A201NORTHSOUTHSITEELEVATIONS.pdf)
/UF (A201NORTHSOUTHSITEELEVATIONS.pdf)
/Desc ()
>>
endobj
```

And if I add /D[0/Fit] command to /S /GoToR manually using notepad, then the link works. D=So how do I add this using pdfbox library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
PDPageDestination dest = new PDPageFitDestination();
dest.setPageNumber(0);
remoteGoto.setD(dest.getCOSObject());
```

Alternatively, just create a `COSArray` and add 0 and `COSName.getPDFName("Fit")` and pass that one to `setD()`.